# Qt5 QWaitCondition example

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am getting myself familiar with QT5 concurrency library. I was looking at the QWaitCondition example (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qwaitcondition.html#details).
Here, one thread (Thread B), reads user input, and all other threads (Thread A) process this input.

**Thread A:**

```
forever {
    mutex.lock();
    keyPressed.wait(&mutex);
    ++count;
    mutex.unlock();

    do_something();

    mutex.lock();
    --count;
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

**Thread B:**

```
forever {
    getchar();

    mutex.lock();
    // Sleep until there are no busy worker threads
    while (count > 0) {
        mutex.unlock();
        sleep(1);
        mutex.lock();
    }
    keyPressed.wakeAll();
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

The reason for using count variable and the extensive mutex synchronization is to prevent symbols loss.
The problem is, I think there is still a chance that a symbol will get lost:
imagine the following scenario:

1. Thread A processes a symbol, and decreases the countes (--count);
   the mutex is released; then Thread A stops
2. Thread B returns from sleep, aquires the mutex, sees, that count ==
       0, and calls keyPressed.wakeAll(), and then unlocks the mutex.
       However, the wakeAll() call goes to nowhere, since the Thread A is
       not waiting.
3. Thread A starts again, aquaires the mutex and goes into wait().
           Since wakeAll() was already called, the symbol is lost.

Am I right, or am I missing something? If I am right, how to correct the example to really prevent it from skipping the symbols?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you are right

to fix this the loop should be entered with the mutex already acquired:

```
mutex.lock();
forever {

    keyPressed.wait(&mutex);
    ++count;
    mutex.unlock();

    do_something();

    mutex.lock();
    --count;

}
mutex.unlock();
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solution still doesn't fix it, because `keyPressed.wait()` internally releases the mutex right before performing actual wait. If Thread A stops the execution in this very moment, then Thread B may take the opportunity of unlocked mutex and perform `wakeAll()`. Thread A is not waiting yet, thus it leads to the same result as in original scenario.

Comment: @doc no the `QWaitCondition` is specifically designed so that any `wake` called after the mutex is unlocked in the call to `wait` will wake the thread calling `wait`.

Comment: Documentation says that mutex is unlocked before wait, so I was suspicious. I've digged the source and it seems that `wakeAll()/wakeOne()` and `wait()` are protected with another mutex so +1.